# Excel - Downsize Array Formula For Multiple Pairs of Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, count, countif, subtotal

I have the following example matrix:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   1   1   1
2   1       1   
3   1   1       
4           1   1
5       1       1
```

My task was to count the number of rows for which at least one pair of columns excluding row A included entries in both columns (e.g., B & C make one pair, D & E make another). In the above example, the answer is 3: row 1 includes entries for both pairs of columns, row 3 includes entries for the first pair of columns (B & C) and row 4 has entries for the second pair of columns (D & E). That's 3 rows which include data for at least one designated pair of columns.

The following array formula achieves the desired results:

```
=COUNT(IFS(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B1,ROW(B1:B5)-ROW(B1),0,1,COLUMNS(B1:C1)))>1,SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1))),SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(D1,ROW(D1:D5)-ROW(D1),0,1,COLUMNS(D1:E1)))>1,SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1)))))
```

The problem is, I have about 30 pairs of columns (some non-adjacent) and a relatively large dataset (up to 10,000 rows). I am looking for a more efficient way to achieve the desired result in an Excel formula. **Note that I wish to avoid creating new rows or columns, which is why I used an array formula**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you're including column A in the example if it is in fact irrelevant.

As such, for the range `B1:E5`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(MMULT((B1:D5<>"")*(C1:E5<>"")*ISEVEN(COLUMN(C1:E5)-MIN(COLUMN(C1:E5))),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COLUMNS(B1:D5)))^0)>0))`

Extend the ranges as required, though note that the part `A:A` within the `INDEX` constructions should remain constant.

No need for CSE with the above.

Regards

Comment: Interesting use of MMULT, thank you. How would I adapt this if my columns were not adjacent, e.g., the two paired columns were B and E rather than B and C?

Comment: And similarly for successive columns, i.e. F and I, J and M, etc.? Or is your data restricted to columns B:E?

Comment: If you are asking about spacing between non-adjacent columns, then it is not always constant, e.g., sometimes its a spacing of 12, sometimes 9, and sometimes 4 depending on where in the database the columns are located. Actual data ranges from A to BD!!

Comment: Then any solution would necessarily require knowledge of which columns are to be 'paired' over the entire range.

Comment: I see. Somehow I was trying to avoid this by perhaps grouping parts of some code with a conditional value indexing the distances between groups of columns (e.g., for columns 12 columns, count how many have entries in each, then for columns 9 columns apart, count how many have entries, etc.). Some sort of chunking code. But I'm too much of a novice to know. Hence why the code I initially posted was so bitty and unparsimonious

Comment: Code? You haven't tagged anything to suggest you were looking for potential VBA solutions as well. And I'm afraid it's still not clear to me what the issue is. Are the columns to be paired not knowable?

Comment: Sorry - I use the term code lightly to refer to formula. The pairings are knowable but if that's the case then they will have to each be specified - as you suggest - which will elongate the code. Technically you have addressed the question so I should really create a new one with a clearer definition of the problem. Many thanks again for your brilliance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182217/discussion-between-pyjamaninja-and-xor-lx).

Comment: Ok, agreed that it might be better to start a new question in this case. And you're welcome!

Comment: Sounds like a VBA routine would be useful here

Comment: Updated question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915579/excel-formula-for-counting-entries-within-multiple-pairs-of-non-sequential-col