# Excel - Formula For Counting Entries Within Multiple Pairs of Non-Sequential Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, count, countif, subtotal

I have the following example matrix:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1       1                               1
3                   1   1       1   1   1                               1
4       1   1   1   1   1                   1      
5           1                   1               1   1   1       1           1
```

**I am trying to count the number of rows for which at least one pair of non-sequential columns excluding row A includes entries in both columns.** The pairs of columns are known but the distance between columns is not constant. In the current example, columns B & K and C & L are paired (distance or d = 9), E & I and F & J are paired (d = 4), and G & S and H & T are paired (d = 12). Notice that column D is not paired with any other column. This frequently occurs: usually the column distance between pairings changes after a column with no intrinsic pairing, e.g., A & E (d = 4), B & F (d = 4), C has no pairing, D & K (d = 7), E & L (d = 7), etc.

In the current example, the number of rows where at least one pair of of columns (as specified above) include entries is 3. For example, row 1 features entries for all pairs of columns, row 3 has entries for column pair F & J, as well as G & S, and row 4 has entries for column pairing C & L.

Here's a sample of an array formula I wrote:

```
=COUNT(IFS(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B1,ROW(B1:B5)-ROW(B1),0,1,COLUMNS(B1:C1)))>1,SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1))),SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(C1,ROW(C1:C5)-ROW(C1),0,1,COLUMNS(C1:D1)))>1,SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1)))))
```

It counts the number of entries for pairs of *sequential* columns (e.g., B & C, C & D). I am unsure how to update it so that it specifies pairs of non-sequential columns (e.g., B & K, C & L, E & I, etc. as specified above).

Here are a few conditions:

- You may not think SUBTOTAL is the most efficient option (e.g., MMULT abd SUBTOTAL might be more appropriate); **however, I am limited to expressing this within a single excel formula (no VBA code, unfortunately). I cannot create new columns or rows either**.
- The matrix entries are not necessarily 1 in the actual matrix, but they are whole numbers (ranging from 1-100).
- Within the full matrix, there are 8 column pairings with a distance = 9, 11 column pairings with a distance of 12, and 3 column pairings with a distance of 3.

Comment: What version of Excel is this for?

Comment: I guess 2013+ but ideally it would be compatible from 2010+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

```
=SUM(IF((
    IF(B1:B5>0,IF(K1:K5>0,1))+
    IF(C1:C5>0,IF(L1:L5>0,1))+
    IF(E1:E5>0,IF(I1:I5>0,1))+
    IF(F1:F5>0,IF(J1:J5>0,1))+
    IF(G1:G5>0,IF(S1:S5>0,1))+
    IF(H1:H5>0,IF(T1:T5>0,1))
) > 0, 1, 0))
```

You can add the remaining pairs in the above list, i have added the ones you have mentioned.

Comment: Hi - many thanks for your response. This works but only if I remove the initial IF, so it becomes:

=SUM((IF(B1:B5>0,IF(K1:K5>0,1))+IF(C1:C5>0,IF(L1:L5>0,1))+IF(E1:E5>0,IF(I1:I5>0,1))+IF(F1:F5>0,IF(J1:J5>0,1))+IF(G1:G5>0,IF(S1:S5>0,1))+IF(H1:H5>0,IF(T1:T5>0,1))))

Comment: The formula you have written will count total number of pairs in your sheet, it will even count if a row has more than one matching pair.
I inserted an additional if to count one row only one time, even if it contains more than one matching pair.
It is working on my side on the data you have provided, are you testing on the same data or the actual data, you can provide some additional data to test it and I can improve the formula.

Comment: Ignore me - I seem to have forgotten the conditions my own problem. This works perfectly. Thank you so much.